# How to check AllowAnonymousAttribute in ActionExecutingContext in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

`System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor` has method `IsDefined` which helps to determine whether one or more instances of the specified attribute type are defined for this member.

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionExecutingContext` does not have this method.

How can I check `AllowAnonymousAttribute` using `ActionExecutingContext` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActionExecutingContext` gives you `ActionDescriptor`. From there, you can check the action metadata for `AllowAnonymousAttribute`.

```cs
class MyFilter: IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var isAnonymous = context.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata.OfType<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any();
        // ...

        return next();
    }
}
```